# Does BitMinter not use CPU's for mining at all?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-software, cpu-mining

I just started using BitMinter on several computers. They have decent GPU's that are detected and working fine, but I'd like to be able to use my CPU's also and I can't seem to find any method to enable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPUs are obsolete for mining. You won't get any reward worth even close to your electricity and hardware degredation cost. This has been true for over a year at least.

CPUs are 1000x more wasteful.

You're too late to the home-mining game.

Answer (score 2):

Your only real option is to mine for other alt coins (with your GPUs) that use an encryption algorithm for which ASICs have not yet been developed. Bitcoin GPU mining is not efficient. CPU mining is even worse.

Comment: What other coin options would you recommend? LiteCoin?

Comment: LiteCoin is scrypt based, and there are already ASICs for that. Your only real option is X11 or X13, so one of these will work well: DarkCoin (DRK), CryptCoin (CRYPT), LitecoinX (LTCX) or Urea (URO).

Answer (score 0):

It does have one, but it's slower than other CPU miners.

Not that this matters, as other posters have noted. Half of nothing is still nothing.

[Source](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=22432.msg1129230#msg1129230)

> DrHaribo, Bitminter.com Operator, posted:
>
> BitMinter client has a very slow CPU implementation. Since CPUs are next to useless for mining it is not a priority to improve this.